# What is wrong with this eval usage?

Tags: php

I have this code in an old, unmaintened woocommerce plugin, for which the author is not around any more and it throws the following error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/woobrdg/api.php(24) : eval()'d code on line 1"

Any suggestions on how to rectify it?

```
public function custom_json_decode( $json ){

    $comment = false;
    $out = '$x=';
    for ($i=0; $i<strlen($json); $i++)
    {
        if (!$comment)
        {
            if (($json[$i] == '{') || ($json[$i] == '['))
                $out .= ' array(';
            else if (($json[$i] == '}') || ($json[$i] == ']'))
                $out .= ')';
            else if ($json[$i] == ':')
                $out .= '=>';
            else
                $out .= $json[$i];
        }
        else
            $out .= $json[$i];
        if ($json[$i] == '"' && $json[($i-1)]!="\\")
            $comment = !$comment;
    }

     eval($out . ';');

    return ( object )$x;

}
```

Comment: do.. not.. use.. eval..

Comment: How to rectify? Delete that code - depending on what $json is / can be your servers are already compromised.

Comment: What's wrong with using the regular json_decode()?

Comment: Use json_decode() ???